# Laravel 5 - looping over a Collection

Tags: laravel-5

can't seem to figure this out.  I have the following code

```
dd($this->project->dsReportingDoc->reportingDocUpload);
if(!empty($this->project->dsReportingDoc->reportingDocUpload)) {
    dd("TEST");
    foreach($this->project->dsReportingDoc->reportingDocUpload as $key){

    }
}
```

Now the first dd prints out something like the following

```
Collection {#274 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => ReportingDocUpload {#275 ▶}
    1 => ReportingDocUpload {#276 ▶}
  ]
}
```

So, there are two items in the Collection.  However, the second dd never seems to get executed, so it must never make it into the if statement.

If anything is in the collection, I need to loop them and get a parameter.  So I need to see if the item exists first.

Why would my if statement be failing here when it is not empty?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if($this->project->dsReportingDoc->reportingDocUpload) {
   dd("TEST");
   foreach($this->project->dsReportingDoc->reportingDocUpload as $key){

   }
}
```

What you can do is, assign the

```
$this->project->dsReportingDoc->reportingDocUpload
```

to a variable so you don't have to rewrite it every where.

Answer (score 3):

The `dd()` debug function stops execution of the current request. So you can only call it once and get output - see [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-dd).

This is the reason your `if` condition and `foreach` aren't executing.